# Prestashop 1.7.4.2 - TCDPF Generate Barcode in Invoice Error

Tags: php, tcpdf, prestashop-1.7, invoice

I am using TCDPF to generate barcode in invoice. Thus, when I download invoice by clicking "View Invoice" from Orders page, it should download with a barcode generated. At the moment, I am just testing a random number.

In HTMLTemplateInvoice.php, I added the following codes:

```
// Random number for testing
$barcodeobj = new TCPDFBarcode('1234567890123', 'C39');

// Assign to template
   // All other unnecessary variables not displayed
   'barcode' => base64_encode($barcodeobj->getBarcodePNG(1, 30, array(255,255,255))),
);
```

For testing purpose, I added the following codes in invoice.addresses.tab.tpl

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{$barcode}>">
```

The barcode is displayed. Unfortunately, it is dislaying as a page and it is not generated in the invoice. The invoice will not download too.

[image: Barcode generated as page]

I am using Prestashop 1.7.4.2 and upgraded to PHP 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this code

```
$barcodeobj = new TCPDFBarcode("123456789123", 'C39');       
$Barcode = $barcodeobj->getBarcodePngData(2, 40, array(0,0,0));
```

and then i created a new pdf :

```
$Barcode_pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A5', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$Barcode_pdf->SetMargins(7, 10.4, 8);
$Barcode_pdf->setImageScale(0.5);
$Barcode_pdf->AddPage();
$Barcode_pdf->Image('@'.$Barcode,'10','20','60' );
$Barcode_pdf->Output('Barcode.pdf', 'I')
```

you can attach it to email if you want **but change the output type to 'S'**:

```
$Barcode_attachment = array();
$Barcode_attachment['content'] = $Barcode_pdf->Output('Barcode.pdf', 'S');
$Barcode_attachment['name'] = 'Barcode.pdf'; // getting pdf file name
$Barcode_attachment['invoice']['mime'] = 'application/pdf';
$Barcode_attachment['mime'] = 'application/pdf';
```

and then just add `$Barcode_attachment` to your email .